# Finding the asymptotic variance of an estimator

Tags: statistics, variance, parameter-estimation, delta-method

Suppose X1, . . . , Xn are independent and exponential with parameter θ.
Let p me an estimator such that
p = #{i : Xi > 1}/n
Where #A is the number of of elements in A.

The original question is to find the asymptotic efficiency but part of it requires me to find the asymptotic variance of -log p. I know I need to find the expectation of p and then use the delta method to find the Asymptotic variance but am struggling to find  the expectation.

Comment: It's better to name specific problems that arose when trying to use the delta method, etc.

Comment: You may want to define $I_k=1_{\{X_k=1\}}$ so that $p=\frac{\sum_{1\leq k\leq n} I_k}{n}$. It should be clear now that $p$ is asymptotically normal.